# Использование метода Android KTX в Java коде

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-ktx

Можно ли каким-либо образом использовать метод `Context.toast(text: CharSequence, duration: Int = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)` из пакета `androidx.core.widget` в Java коде? Например, я импортирую данный метод:

```
import static androidx.core.widget.ToastKt.toast;
```

и далее пытаюсь использовать его:

```
toast((CharSequence) errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

однако в этом случае Android Studio подчёркивает его красным с предупреждением "cannot resolve method toast". Возможно ли вообще использовать метод этот метод в Java коде?

Comment: По идее как-то так должно сработать: `ToastKt.toast(context, (CharSequence) errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);` ну или так: `toast(context, (CharSequence) errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);` - т.е. надо явно передать контекст, что, собственно, лишает смысла использование из явы этого метода расширения)

Comment: Да, Вы правы) `toast(getContext(), errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);` работает. И это короче, чем `Toast.makeText(getContext(), errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`, так что, может, не совсем лишает?..) Хотя, конечно, уже не так коротко, как в Котлин =(

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, и оформите как ответ, обязательно приму)

Comment: а с anko так ваще минимализм :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По идее как-то так должно сработать:

```
ToastKt.toast(context, (CharSequence) errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

ну или так:

```
toast(context, (CharSequence) errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

т.е. надо явно передать контекст, что, собственно, лишает смысла использование из явы этого метода расширения)